# Identity involving cosine of double angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am struggling to see this.

I know that we can factor out $ a$, but I don't see how we can end up with the right hand side.

$$a \cos ^2(a t)-a \sin ^2(a t)=a \cos (2 a t)$$

Comment: Are you asking about how the derivatives of both sides are the same?

Comment: I *think* the word is "derivation"...

Comment: Sorry it the result from finding the derivative of a function, and I could not simplify the result. I should have used derivation since I didnt show that part in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**
just be aware that $\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$, is just a special case of
$$\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta$$
try to prove this by finding the length of the green line (see graphic)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$\cos(2x)=\cos^{2}(x)-\sin^{2}(x)$$

Comment: Perfect can you show the proof?

Comment: A proof through geometry can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_trigonometric_identities
Notice that the above follows from the angle sum identities.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
a cos(2 a t) &=a Re \left[e^{2 i a t} \right] \\
&=a Re \left[ \left( e^{i a t} \right)^2 \right] \\
&= a Re \left[ \left(cos( a t) + i sin( a t) \right)^2 \right] \\
&= a Re \left[ cos^2(a t) - sin^2(a t) + 2 i cos(a t) sin(a t) \right] \\
&= a cos^2 (a t) - a sin^2 (a t)
\end{align}
$$

where I made use of the Euler identity $e^{i x} = cos(x) + i sin(x)$.